# How to enable debug logs for j2ssh maverick?

Tags: java, ssh, log4j, sftp, j2ssh

Recently I am using `j2ssh-maverick-1.5.5.jar` for implementing `sftp` within my own java application, but I got a problem on enabling debug message via `log4j.properties`.

It seems it didn't work on `log4j.logger.com.sshtools=DEBUG`

I can find similar topic from `sshtools` limited: "How to enable debug logs for Maverick versions 1.4.x", but I am not using `maverick-legacy-client.jar`.

Could anyone tell me how can I show debug log message using `j2ssh-maverick-1.5.5.jar`?

Answer (score 0):

J2SSH Maverick uses its own logging interface [Logger](https://github.com/sshtools/j2ssh-maverick/blob/master/j2ssh-maverick/src/main/java/com/sshtools/logging/Logger.java)

But if you just want simple logging to System.out just use the [SimpleLogger](https://github.com/sshtools/j2ssh-maverick/blob/master/j2ssh-maverick/src/main/java/com/sshtools/logging/SimpleLogger.java) by calling

```
LoggerFactory.setInstance(new SimpleLogger(LoggerLevel.DEBUG));
```

Answer (score 0):

In j2ssh-maverick-1.5.5 you need to create a new Class that implements [Logger](https://github.com/sshtools/j2ssh-maverick/blob/master/j2ssh-maverick/src/main/java/com/sshtools/logging/Logger.java) interface. This is an example:

```
import com.sshtools.logging.Logger;
import com.sshtools.logging.LoggerLevel;
    
public class J2sshLogger implements Logger{
    LoggerLevel level;

    public J2sshLogger(LoggerLevel arg0) {
        level = arg0;
    }

    public boolean isLevelEnabled(LoggerLevel level) {
        return (this.level.ordinal() >= level.ordinal());
    }

    public void log(LoggerLevel level, Object source, String msg) {
        //here your log: example log.write(level, msg);
    }

    public void log(LoggerLevel level, Object source, String msg, Throwable t) {
        //here your log: example log.write(level, msg);
    }
}
```

When you create your SSH connection you need to set your new logger class to [LoggerFactory](https://github.com/sshtools/j2ssh-maverick/blob/master/j2ssh-maverick/src/main/java/com/sshtools/logging/LoggerFactory.java), like this:

```
LoggerFactory.setInstance(new J2sshLogger(LoggerLevel.INFO));
```